# populate: listview from json

Tags: android, json, listview

I want to populate a listview from my json which looks like this:

```
{ library: { books: [ { name: "name", autor: "autor",year: "year"}, { name: "name", autor: "autor", year: "year"}], library: { name: "name"}}}
```

In main activity i have this method

```
public void books() {

    request = new JsonRequestClass(getContext(), JsonMethodClass.GET, null);
    try {
        String response = request.execute("http://booksjson").get();

        ResponseListModel responseListModel = new ResponseListModel(response);
        if (responseListModel.isSuccess() == true) {

        } else {
            responseListModel.setSuccess(false);
            responseListModel.setMessage("Error");
            //Toast.makeText(getContext(), responseListModel.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

this method help me to read the json 
but how do i populate the listview if i have a void method and in my adapter class is waiting for an arraylist from model class?

```
public BookAdapter(Context context, List<Book> list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}
```

I-m adding my ResponseListModel model class

```
public class ResponseListModel {

    private boolean success;
    private String message;
    private JSONArray list;
    private JSONObject object;

    public ResponseListModel(String pObjetc) {
        try {

            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(pObjetc);

            this.message = object.getString("message");
            this.success = object.getBoolean("success");
            //response.setMessage(object.optString("message"));
            String strModel = object.getString("strModel");
            String type = object.optString("type");
            if (type.equals("array")) {
                this.list = object.getJSONArray("model");// new JSONArray(strModel);
            } else
                object = object.getJSONObject("model");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public JSONArray getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public JSONObject getObject() {
        return object;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void setList(JSONArray list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void setObject(JSONObject object) {
        this.object = object;
    }
}
```

And to be more specific i need help on this line on my main

```
adapter = new BookAdapter(this, books);
```

Comment: You have to parse the string in `response` to an array or list of `Book`. I don't know this class `ResponseListModel` but it seems to do the job. So, probably, there is some method like `getBody()`, `getModel()` or `getResponse()` to be called from the `responseListModel` instance that should return the list/array you need. Maybe you have to do some cast too.

Comment: i added the responselistmodel class maybe you can give me a hand?

Comment: But did you create this class yourself or is it some library class?

Comment: @DiegoMagdaleno i created it

Comment: So, if you wanna keep this strategy, you should now implement a json parser to convert your string in objects. Take a look at this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm - But I should say that this is not best way to do that. There are plenty of good parsers available like jackson or gson.

Comment: the thing is, i dont know how to do it with my json structure, i saw a lot examples with differents structures than this one and whenever i try to adapt it doesnt works

Comment: If you want to write your own parser, you got to make sure the json structure is the one you are expecting for. You can achieve this by printing your `response` string. After that, you can see if it is right to parse your array from `model` in the `ResponseListModel` class. Again, here is a simple example using jackson: https://www.codexpedia.com/java/jackson-parser-example-in-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to deserialize your json array response to arraylist of java object. You can use default Json [android json package](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary) or [gson library](https://github.com/google/gson) to do that.

Then you can feed your adapter with that arraylist of your Book class objects.

For more details you can refer to [json to recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966477/how-to-show-other-jsonarray-in-recyclerview-on-android).

FYI: You should use updated version of listview which is [Recyclerview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

Happy coding......:)

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert that `response` variable into a `java class`, you can use clases like `Gson` and annotations.

You may check [this page](https://jsoneditoronline.org/) and paste your JSON to help you understand its structure.