# how can i parse JSON response

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have JSON response and it have JSON array inside JSON array. Please tell me how to parse it. and please tell me it's best example for multiple JSON array parsing. I have all field dynamic so developer give me this kind of response. Thanks in advance.

```
    {
"products": [
    {
      "id": "14",
      "cat_id": [
        "1"
      ],
      "category_name": [
        "Meetha Paan Sall Supari"
      ],
      "name": "Chocco Paan",
      "product_image": "http://freedemo.info/paanvaala/php/media/product_image/t0xdfosjr_1_173_201.png",
      "price_unit": "in_pcs",
      "price_id": [
        "14"
      ],
      "weight": [
        "1 PCS"
      ],
      "price": [
        150
      ],
      "mrp": [
        "150.00"
      ],
      "description": null
    },
    {
      "id": "13",
      "cat_id": [
        "1"
      ],
      "category_name": [
        "Meetha Paan Sall Supari"
      ],
      "name": "Chochobar Pan",
      "product_image": "http://freedemo.info/paanvaala/php/media/product_image/hul6e69n6_1_173_201.png",
      "price_unit": "in_pcs",
      "price_id": [
        "13"
      ],
      "weight": [
        "1 PCS"
      ],
      "price": [
        85
      ],
      "mrp": [
        "85.00"
      ],
      "description": null
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: This question could benefit from additional formatting and clarification. What's your use case? What data do you want to extract from it?

Comment: search on google before you post , there are tones of example

Comment: lot of examples existed try it out first,You will get better knowledge.

Comment: i am confuse because there are more array in this response and i want to extract all item from this response

Comment: Your json structure is wrong

Comment: hey @keyurhudka I think your json is wrong Please post your json correctly so that I can help you.

Comment: yeah..you can test it here: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ 
you are missing a `]` before the last `}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: remove last 2 commas after description

  your JSON :   "description": null
    },
  ],
}

Correct JSON : "description": null
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

How to Parse JSON and what its has in it Follow [**here**](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/).

[image]

Comment: i want example that parse multiple json array

Answer (score 0):

parse json:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);// your string.
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("products");


for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
       JSONObject prod = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
       String id = prod.getString("id");

       // and so on ...you can parse the entire json using either array or object

}
```

surround with try catch for exception....

Answer (score 0):

First you need to verif y if your JSON is valid or not.
[Json Validator](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/)

if you find this valid then `

```
try { JSONObject  jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(strJson);
         //Get the instance of JSONArray that contains JSONObjects
         JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("products");   
         //Iterate the jsonArray and print the info of JSONObjects
         for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            int id = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.optString("id").toString());
            String name = jsonObject.optString("name").toString();
            float product_image = Float.parseFloat(jsonObject.optString("product_image").toString());
         JSONArray cat_idArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("cat_id");    
         for(int i=0; i < cat_idArray.length(); i++){
        //Here you can get other values
           }
            data += "Node"+i+" : \n id= "+ id +" \n Name= "+ name +" \n Salary= "+ salary +" \n ";
         }
         output.setText(data);
      } catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

`
Also there are lots of example in web where you can learn.
[like this one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Json parsing is all about understanding the hierarchy of objects '{}' and array '[]' . you can look at following links to understand it. 
[How to parse this nested JSON array in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673057/how-to-parse-this-nested-json-array-in-android)
or http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/06/10/complex-json-string-parsing-in-android/