# How to parse a big JSON file in android Like This

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

how to parse a json like this :
[image: screnshot_one]
[image: screnshot_one]

Comment: What have you done so far? Show your code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673057/how-to-parse-this-nested-json-array-in-android/17673362#17673362. Check, It may help you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is using from **Gson Library** from Google refer to this link : [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)