# How to get the inner array from json in android?

Tags: android

```
{"Suggestions":[{"Itinerary_1":[{"Cities":"Madurai - Pazhamudir Cholai (Madurai) - Pillayarpatti - Chennai","Citieids":"14-85-114-2","Kms":595}],"Itinerary_2":[{"Cities":"Madurai - Pillayarpatti - Pillayarpatti - Chennai","Citieids":"14-114-114-2","Kms":560}],"Itinerary_3":[{"Cities":"Madurai - Pillayarpatti - Pillayarpatti - Chennai","Citieids":"14-114-114-2","Kms":560}]}]}
```

This my json response.This json have a inner array how can i get the value

This my code:

```
class itinerarydetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;


            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("orgin", "14"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("destination", "2"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("orgin_date", "28/06/2017"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("destination_date", "07/07/2017"));

             json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(itineraryurl, "GET",
                    params);
            try {

                //Suggestions
                jsonarray = json.getJSONArray("Suggestions");
               // JSONArray list = mainObj.getJSONArray("prodCat_list");

                String check;
                if(jsonarray != null) {
                   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationCon                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          text(), "MAIN ARRAY IS NOT EMPTY ITS HAVE A VALUE",
                    //  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Log.d("check","MAIN ARRAY IS NOT EMPTY ITS HAVE A VALUE");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                        //   JSONObject elem = list.getJSONObject(i);

                        JSONObject object = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        //JSONArray prods = elem.getJSONArray("prods");

                        jsoninsidearray = object.getJSONArray("Itinerary_1");

                        if(jsoninsidearray != null) {

                            Log.d("check","INSIDE ARRAY IS NOT EMPTY ITS HAVE A VALUE");

                            for (int j = 0; j < jsoninsidearray.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject innerElem = jsoninsidearray.getJSONObject(j);


                                if(innerElem != null) {


                                    Log.d("check","innerElement ARRAY IS NOT EMPTY ITS HAVE A VALUE");
                                    cityjson = innerElem.getString("Cities");
                                    itinerary = innerElem.getString("Citieids");
                                    totalkms = innerElem.getString("Kms");

                                }
                               else
                                {
                                    Log.d("check","innerElement ARRAY IS EMPTY");

                                }

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "INSIDE ARRAY IS EMPTY",
                                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            Log.d("check","INSIDE ARRAY IS EMPTY");
                        }


                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MAIN ARRAY IS EMPTY",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Log.d("check","MAIN ARRAY IS EMPTY");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hai",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cityjson, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        }

    }
```

I am Vignesh i have a doubt so pls help in this below
but empty values has displayed.how can i get the values from inner array from json.

Comment: I think this answers your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673057/how-to-parse-this-nested-json-array-in-android

Comment: In this,there is the Suggestion Array in that there are three different Array("Itinerary_1","Itinerary_2","Itinerary_3") .but the answer given by You has (prodCat_list) array and it has a Multiple array but everything Has same name so it could be called easily.I have also tried out this idea but it displays the empty value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse this nested JSON array in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673057/how-to-parse-this-nested-json-array-in-android)

Comment: object.getJSONArray("Itinerary_"+ (i+1))   is perfect because there is no "Itinerary_0". Than it i will stop parsing dear.  Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Change this line  `jsoninsidearray = object.getJSONArray("Itinerary_1");`

**to**

```
jsoninsidearray = object.getJSONArray("Itinerary_"+i);
```

Comment: Ok Try this and let me know if you have any query

Comment: Thanks for Your Response. I tried it out but only empty value is displayed.

Comment: Just for my future understanding, how is the 2nd code different from the first?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) 
{
JSONObject object = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

   

     jsoninsidearray = object.getJSONArray("Itinerary_1"); // Instead of Itinerary_1,Itinerary_2,Itinerary_3

 jsoninsidearray = object.getJSONArray("Itinerary_"+i); //
}
In the above code instead of using  Instead of  using "Itinerary_1,Itinerary_2,Itinerary_3" like this We could use [Itinerary_"+i] like this which could call entirely.

Comment: any doubt please ask me.

Comment: @VIgneshJeyaraj check your response and in response check a parameter named  "Itinerary_2" this key is contentiously  change that's why i put a  object.getJSONArray("Itinerary_"+i); so it will pass to i++ and your Itinerary_1,Itinerary_2,Itinerary_3...so on and able to read your response

Comment: Post my solution for problem

Answer (score 3):

Let's try to understand the structure of your input JSON object.

- Suggestions (JSONArray)

  - First Object (JSONObject)

    - Itinerary_1 (JSONArray)

      - First Object (JSONObject)

        - cities (String)
        - citieids (String)
        - kms (String)
    - Itinerary_2 (JSONArray)

      - First Object (JSONObject)

        - cities (String)
        - citieids (String)
        - kms (String)
    - Itinerary_3 (JSONArray)

      - First Object (JSONObject)

        - cities (String)
        - citieids (String)
        - kms (String)
  - Second Object (JSONObject)

    - Itinerary_1 (JSONArray)

      - First Object (JSONObject)

        - cities (String)
        - citieids (String)
        - kms (String)
    - Itinerary_2 (JSONArray)

      - First Object (JSONObject)

        - cities (String)
        - citieids (String)
        - kms (String)
    - Itinerary_3 (JSONArray)

      - First Object (JSONObject)

        - cities (String)
        - citieids (String)
        - kms (String)
  - so on ....

formatted JSON Object

```
{
   "Suggestions":[
      {
         "Itinerary_1":[
            {
               "Cities":"Madurai - Pazhamudir Cholai (Madurai) - Pillayarpatti - Chennai",
               "Citieids":"14-85-114-2",
               "Kms":595
            }
         ],
         "Itinerary_2":[
            {
               "Cities":"Madurai - Pillayarpatti - Pillayarpatti - Chennai",
               "Citieids":"14-114-114-2",
               "Kms":560
            }
         ],
         "Itinerary_3":[
            {
               "Cities":"Madurai - Pillayarpatti - Pillayarpatti - Chennai",
               "Citieids":"14-114-114-2",
               "Kms":560
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Hence your code should have an additional for loop to loop over 3 itinerary elements of each JSONObject inside Suggestions.

Here is the updated code, check out the new for loop added with index as the iteration counter.

```
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{\"Suggestions\":[{\"Itinerary_1\":[{\"Cities\":\"Madurai - Pazhamudir Cholai (Madurai) - Pillayarpatti - Chennai\",\"Citieids\":\"14-85-114-2\",\"Kms\":595}],\"Itinerary_2\":[{\"Cities\":\"Madurai - Pillayarpatti - Pillayarpatti - Chennai\",\"Citieids\":\"14-114-114-2\",\"Kms\":560}],\"Itinerary_3\":[{\"Cities\":\"Madurai - Pillayarpatti - Pillayarpatti - Chennai\",\"Citieids\":\"14-114-114-2\",\"Kms\":560}]}]}");
        JSONArray jsonarray = json.getJSONArray("Suggestions");
        if(jsonarray != null) {
            Log.d("check","MAIN ARRAY IS NOT EMPTY ITS HAVE A VALUE");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                // ** START NEW FOR LOOP
                for (int index=1; index < 4; index++) {
                    Log.d("check","-------------------------");
                    Log.d("check","Print Itinerary_" + (index));
                    JSONArray jsoninsidearray = object.getJSONArray("Itinerary_" + index);
                    if(jsoninsidearray != null) {
                        Log.d("check","INSIDE ARRAY IS NOT EMPTY ITS HAVE A VALUE");
                        for (int j = 0; j < jsoninsidearray.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject innerElem = jsoninsidearray.getJSONObject(j);
                            if(innerElem != null) {
                                Log.d("check","innerElement ARRAY IS NOT EMPTY ITS HAVE A VALUE");
                                String cityjson = innerElem.getString("Cities");
                                String itinerary = innerElem.getString("Citieids");
                                String totalkms = innerElem.getString("Kms");
                                Log.d("check", cityjson + " | " + itinerary + " | " + totalkms);
                            } else {
                                Log.d("check","innerElement ARRAY IS EMPTY");
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d("check","INSIDE ARRAY IS EMPTY");
                    }
                } // ** END NEW FOR LOOP
            Log.d("check", "");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("check","MAIN ARRAY IS EMPTY");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Sample Run

```
07-03 22:03:05.028 30616-30616/a D/check: MAIN ARRAY IS NOT EMPTY ITS HAVE A VALUE
07-03 22:03:05.028 30616-30616/a D/check: --------------------------
07-03 22:03:05.028 30616-30616/a D/check: Print Itinerary_1
07-03 22:03:05.028 30616-30616/a D/check: INSIDE ARRAY IS NOT EMPTY ITS HAVE A VALUE
07-03 22:03:05.028 30616-30616/a D/check: innerElement ARRAY IS NOT EMPTY ITS HAVE A VALUE
07-03 22:03:05.028 30616-30616/a D/check: Madurai - Pazhamudir Cholai (Madurai) - Pillayarpatti - Chennai | 14-85-114-2 | 595
07-03 22:03:05.028 30616-30616/a D/check: --------------------------
07-03 22:03:05.028 30616-30616/a D/check: Print Itinerary_2
07-03 22:03:05.028 30616-30616/a D/check: INSIDE ARRAY IS NOT EMPTY ITS HAVE A VALUE
07-03 22:03:05.028 30616-30616/a D/check: innerElement ARRAY IS NOT EMPTY ITS HAVE A VALUE
07-03 22:03:05.029 30616-30616/a D/check: Madurai - Pillayarpatti - Pillayarpatti - Chennai | 14-114-114-2 | 560
07-03 22:03:05.029 30616-30616/a D/check: --------------------------
07-03 22:03:05.029 30616-30616/a D/check: Print Itinerary_3
07-03 22:03:05.029 30616-30616/a D/check: INSIDE ARRAY IS NOT EMPTY ITS HAVE A VALUE
07-03 22:03:05.029 30616-30616/a D/check: innerElement ARRAY IS NOT EMPTY ITS HAVE A VALUE
07-03 22:03:05.029 30616-30616/a D/check: Madurai - Pillayarpatti - Pillayarpatti - Chennai | 14-114-114-2 | 560
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.This code perfectly works sir. but only output displayed in static data. not retrieve the data from from json(Dynamically).  I think the problem is **JSON ARRAY** not converted into **JSON OBJECT**

Comment: I didn't get your comments, I can help if you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

May this will help you

```
JSONObject mainObj = = new JSONObject(response);

JSONArray Suggestionslist = mainObj.getJSONArray("Suggestions");
    if(Suggestionslist != null){

    for(int i = 0; i < Suggestionslist.length();i++){
             JSONObject elem = list.getJSONObject(i);
            if(elem != null){
                 JSONArray Itinerary = elem.getJSONArray("Itinerary_"+ (i+1));
                if(Itinerary != null){ 

                       for(int j = 0; j < Itinerary.length();j++){
                        JSONObject innerElem = Itinerary.getJSONObject(j);
                        if(innerElem != null){
                            String Cities = innerELem.getString("Cities");
                            String Citieids = innerElem.getString("Citieids");
                            String Kms = innerElem.getString("Kms");
                        }
                    }  

                 }
    }

}
```

Comment: If any problem occure please mention

Comment: What is result?  "Itinerary_"+ (i+1) is perfect because there is no "Itinerary_0". Than it i will stop parsing dear.

Comment: Thanks for Your Response. I tried it out but only empty value is displayed

Answer (score 0):

here you have to create jsonobject first try this

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);  
JSONArray data = object.getJSONArray("Suggestions");   

        JSONObject obj1 = data.getJSONObject(0);

            JSONArray inner = obj1.getJSONArray("Itinerary_1");
            String Cities=inner.getString(0);
            String Citiesids=inner.getString(1);
            String Kms=inner.getString(2);
//and so on copy and change the name of Itinerary_*

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Complete Solution for innerArray

```
      if (status == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);



            JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("Suggestions");

            System.out.println("====================///////////" + jarray);
            if (jarray != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);


                    System.out.print("obj//////////" + object.length() + "\n");
                    int m;


                    for (int i1 = 1; i1 <= object.length(); i1++) {

                        System.out.println("inner======  inside second for loop  =====");

                        JSONArray jarray1 = object.getJSONArray("Itinerary_" + i1);

                        JSONObject object1 = jarray1.getJSONObject(i);

                        //JSONObject jsoninside = object.getJSONObject("Itinerary_"+ i1);

                        System.out.println("inner====================///////////\\\\" + object1);

                        if (object1 != null) {
                            citynames = object1.getString("Cities");
                            citykms = object1.getString("Kms");

                        } else {
                            Log.d("check", "INSIDE ARRAY IS EMPTY");
                        }


                    }

                    return true;
                }

            }
        } else {
            Log.d("check", "MAIN ARRAY IS EMPTY");
        }
```

Comment: This code Working Perfectly (any queries please add comment).I will Explain